# SonarQube analysis of guava v18 - InternalPrefixUnaryExpression cannot be cast to MethodInvocationTree

Tags: maven, sonarqube, guava

Using SonarQube 6.3.1 server, org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.2 and 3.3.0.603, Apache Maven 3.5.0, Java version: 1.8.0_91, vendor: Oracle Corporation, running Fedora 25

Steps to reproduce:

- git clone --branch v18.0 https://github.com/google/guava.git
- cd guava
- mvn -X org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.3.0.603:sonar

Posting this error here as I'm not allowed to create issue sonarsource jira

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.2:sonar (default-cli) on project guava-parent: SonarQube is unable to analyze file : '/home/rsvoboda/tmp/guava/guava/src/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Monitor.java': org.sonar.java.model.expression.InternalPrefixUnaryExpression cannot be cast to org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.MethodInvocationTree -> [Help 1]

To me this is bug, I could get further using workaround: -Dsonar.exclusions=**/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Monitor.java

Comment: Which version of the sonarJava plugin is installed on the server ? Can you post the full stack trace ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell you are hitting this problem : https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-2140 Which has been fixed in version 4.6 of SonarJava analyzer. (bundled version with SonarQube 6.3.1 is 4.5, consider upgrading it to latest version 4.9 at time of writing).

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that update of SonarJava analyzer via updatecenter to the latest version (4.9) available helps. Thank you @benzonico for help.